# Connected components when you can't visualize the space

Tags: general-topology

> Let $U = (\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{(0,0)\}) \cup (\{(0,0)\} \times \mathbb{R^2})$. How many connected components does $\mathbb{R}^4 \setminus U$ have?

It is bit hard to visualize this so I couldn't figure this out pictorially. What I thought was that we're removing two planes from $\mathbb{R}^4$ so that would give some separation for the components, but it is not clear in my head. How can we compute the connected components when we cant visualize them?

Comment: If I recall correctly, there is some theorem saying that removing subset, whose dimension is at least 2 less than the euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$ (or $S^n$), cannot change number of components. Although it might be an overkill here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an idea you could use to cook up rigorous solution.

---

Show the space $X = \mathbb R^4 \setminus U$ is path-connected: given arbitrary point $(x, y, z, t)\in X$ you could connect it always with one of the points of the form
$(\pm1, \pm1, \pm1, \pm1)$ with single line segment.

Every line segment spanned by 2 points of the form $(\pm1, \pm1, \pm1, \pm1)$, which differ on only 1 coordinate, is contained in $X$. Therefore any 2 points of that form can be joined using 4 line segments or less.

All together any 2 points in $X$ could be connected using at most 6 line segments.

---

This approach would also work when you remove every possible 2-dimensional plane spanned by some pair of standard basis vectors, not only those 2.